# How Label Propagation Algorithm works?

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory

I am testing *Graph Algorithms* in my graph stored in **Neo4j** database.
i read [the documentation of the label propagation algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/label-propagation/) and what i understand is at the end of the algorithm my graph would be clustered in groups with different labels .

My questions are :

1) Is my understanding true ?

2) If yes, from where this labels come from ? if my graph nodes are all labeled with just one label named **:HashNode**?

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j labels and labels from label propagation graph algorithm are not the same.

Label propagation algorithm will get its starting labels from id of nodes, so each node has a unique label at the start of algorithm.

> Every node is initialized with a unique label (an identifier).

Comment: thanks for that information, but what would i expect  from this algorithm, a clustering ? what information this clustering would give me ? it's not clear